# Using libnvvm for code optimization

Tags: cuda, llvm

NVCC has its own IR representation called NVVM which is a subet of LLVM IR. I read that libnvvm can be used to perform optimization on NVVM IR but I am not able to find any tutorial or beginners guide to use libnvvm?
Can anybody share some material regarding this?
Basically, how do I write an optimization pass? or even how do i write simple pretty printer using libnvvm?

Answer (score 1):

The NVVM IR specification is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvvm-ir-spec/index.html)

The libnvvm API documentation is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/libnvvm-api/index.html)

The CUDA LLVM compiler SDK is available [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-llvm-compiler), including sample apps, demonstrating how to use libnvvm.

The NVVM IR verifier sample should give you a good framework for a simple pretty printer.